# how to call address dynamic block in template file with arguments?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, customer-address, dynamic-blocks

Hi here is my code in the layout XML file.

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="Magento_Customer::address/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="attribute_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData</argument>
        <argument name="post_code_config" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\PostCodesPatternsAttributeData</argument>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I would like to call the above block using dynamic block in my template file called `custom.phtml`
Here is what I tried, but no luck.

Below code, I am trying in `custom.phtml` file.

```
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <?php
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $attribute_data = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData');
        $post_code_config = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\PostCodesPatternsAttributeData');
        $view_model = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address');
    ?>
    <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit', "customer_address_edit",
        ['attribute_data' => $attribute_data,
        'post_code_config' => $post_code_config,
        'view_model' => $view_model])->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::address/edit.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

When I put the above code in my custom template file it throws the below errors:

> Error: Call to a member function getFrontendLabel() on null in

above error throwing because in address/edit.phtml file there is one code.

```
<?php $_country_id = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id'); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using $block->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_address_edit')->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::address/edit.phtml')->toHtml(); instead of creating a new block instance?

Comment: @MagestyApps unfortunately not works